Is It Possible to Query Claimable Rewards from Nomination Pools in Python?
When a Polkadot address is part of a nomination pool, the following JavaScript code can be used to query the amount of rewards ready to be claimed:
const pendingReward = await api.call.nominationPoolsApi.pendingRewards(accountId);

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the same in Python, either using the substrate-interface module or by directly calling the state_getStorageAt RPC method.
Thank you.

import requests


resp = requests.post(
    "https://rpc.polkadot.io",
    json={
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 0,
        "method": "state_call",
        "params": [
            "NominationPoolsApi_pending_rewards",
            "0x0000966d74f8027e07b43717b6876d97544fe0d71facef06acc8382749ae944e",
            None,
        ],
    },
)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    res = resp.json()

    if "result" in res:
        res = res["result"]

        print(res)


None means fetch the state from the latest block, you can also pass a block hash here to specify the block.
0x0000966d74f8027e07b43717b6876d97544fe0d71facef06acc8382749ae944e is 111B8CxcmnWbuDLyGvgUmRezDCK1brRZmvUuQ6SrFdMyc3S.
You need to use scale codec to decode the res.

